# Wine glass isn't transparent when imported to unity

Tags: materials, export, normals, unity

I've been trying to create this wine glass object for my game and 3D modelling is completely new to me and I followed all the steps of a tutorial to the best of my knowledge.

But when I convert it to fbx and export the object doesn't have the " Glass BDF " material to it; So, I added one of the materials from the material folder that was created when the fbx file was exported but the end **result isn't transparent**.

I **recalculated the normals** but I'm still not getting it.I also checked the **UV swap option**.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think Unity can read materials exported from Cycles. Try Blender Internal and see if that works